# The principal axis of a flat object

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Let's assume that we have a flat object which has a random shape and does not have a symmetry axis. Let's assume the flat object lays in the xy-plane.

Any rigid body in principle has a set of three principal axes, which can be found generally by diagonalizing the matrix corresponding to the inertia tensor.

For this specific object, do the 2 (of the 3) principal axes have to be necessarily in the xy-plane as well? I could not find any general theorem regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a small particle of mass $m_i$ located at $(x_i,y_i)$ on the flat body.

[image: fig1]

The contribution of this particle to the body MMOI tensor about the origin is

$$ {\rm I} = \sum_i  m_{i}\begin{bmatrix}y_{i}^{2} & \text{-}x_{i}y_{i}\\
\text{-}x_{i}y_{i} & x_{i}^{2}\\
 &  & x_{i}^{2}+y_{i}^{2}
\end{bmatrix} $$

with the missing elements above being zero.

In total the general structure of the MMOI tensor is

$$ {\rm I}=\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy}\\
I_{xy} & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now you are asking about the eigenvectors for this matrix, and if it possible to have one that contains components on both *z* and *xy* directions.

There are three eigenvalues for this matrix

$$\begin{aligned}\lambda_{1} & =\frac{I_{xx}+I_{yy}+\sqrt{\left(I_{xx}-I_{yy}\right)^{2}-4I_{xy}}}{2} \\ \lambda_{2} & =\frac{I_{xx}+I_{yy}-\sqrt{\left(I_{xx}-I_{yy}\right)^{2}-4I_{xy}}}{2} \\ \lambda_{3} & =I_{zz}\end{aligned}$$

The first two correspond to eigenvectors that are in-plane (only have *xy* components) and the third one to an eigenvalue with no *xy* components and only a *z* component.

You can confirm this last part readily with $$\left(\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy}\\
I_{xy} & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}-\lambda_{3}\right)\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

and you can show that exists such angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ to also solve the eigenvector problem for the other two eigenvalues

$$\small 
\begin{aligned}\left(\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy}\\
I_{xy} & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}-\lambda_{1}\right)\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_{1}\\
\sin\theta_{1}\\
0
\end{pmatrix} & =\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} & \left(\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy}\\
I_{xy} & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}-\lambda_{2}\right)\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta_{2}\\
\sin\theta_{2}\\
0
\end{pmatrix} & =\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}\end{aligned}$$

But is there a special case with an eigenvector of the form

$$\left(\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx} & I_{xy}\\
I_{xy} & I_{yy}\\
 &  & I_{zz}
\end{bmatrix}-\lambda_{i}\right)\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta\\
\sin\theta\\
e_{z}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$

which means the principal axis comes of the plane but it is *not* parallel to the *z* axis. There is only one special circumstance that this can happen with

$$ I_{xy}=\pm\sqrt{I_{zz}-I_{xx}}\sqrt{I_{zz}-I_{yy}} $$

I am not sure what shape can produce this exact value, and if it physically possible, but in theory it might be possible to produce such as shape. In practice no, because you can never make something with *exact* dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response! So is the conclusion that yes, two principal axes will always be in the plane with the third one in the z direction? And does this mean that the principal axes in the plane are symmetry axes (even if the flat object has a completely random shape?)

Comment: Yes. two principal axis along the  _xy_ plane and the third one along the _z_ axis. These axes not necessarily symmetric axis as the geometry might be abstract.

Comment: I see, but the other way around is true right? If an axis is a symmetry axis, then it must be a principal axis.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of inertia is symmetric, and all symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues and orthogonal eigenvectors, as shown [here](https://builtin.com/data-science/symmetric-matrix).

As one of the axis (eigenvectors) of inertia must of course be parallel to the z-axis, the other 2 must be in the xy axis in order to result in a set of 3 orthogonal axis (eigenvectors).

Comment: But doesn't that imply that the 2 in the xy plane are symmetry axes? Or does that not necessarily have to be the case? Also why does one necessarily have to be the z axis? How do you know there is not some other way to do it?

Comment: A vertical (parallel to z axis) passing through the COM is one of the axis of inertia, due to the symmetry of the object. For a generic shape, there are only 2 orthogonal eingenvectors in the xy plane. In general they don't divide the shape in two equal halves, if it is what you mean by symmetrical axis. But in special cases (if the shape is a circle for example), there are an infinity of eigenvectors there (and symmetric also).